# Is there a way to make Screen scroll like a normal terminal?

Tags: gnu-screen, scrolling

I love screen, but it drives me nuts that I have to stop typing input, hit `CTRL+A [`, and then find what I need.

Is there a way to make the scroll wheel function normally, rather than scrolling commands?

Also, is it possible to enable Shift+PageUp/PageDn?

Comment: Not an answer but [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) makes this much easier.  I've tried to do this in screen before but it seems to always involve mapping arcane escape codes that vary by terminal emulator.

Comment: http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq you probably just have to disable the alternate screen

Comment: just to add a reference: [Scroll inside Screen, or Pause Output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40242/scroll-inside-screen-or-pause-output)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use these settings with urxvt in my ~/.screenrc:

```
termcapinfo rxvt-unicode ti@:te@
termcapinfo rxvt ti@:te@
termcapinfo rxvt 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=07:ds=\E]2;screen07'
```

Those allow for scrollbar and mouse wheel to do "the right thing™".

Note that this is dependent on terminal type, so will not work if your terminal is not of type `rxvt`. If it doesn't work, try replacing `rxvt` and `rxvt-unicode` with the appropriate terminal type (get this by running `printf $TERM`.)

Comment: +1. Using "xterm" instead of "rxvt" and "rxvt-unicode", Shift-PgUp/-PgDown work for me on gnome-terminal. But the mousewheel scrolls in the shell history.

Comment: when using gnome-terminal, mousewheel scrolls normal, i.e. in scrollback.

Comment: When I use screen in gnome-terminal. Don't worry about it...

Comment: This also worked for me using `xterm` in place of `rvxt*`. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what each of these command do, please?

Comment: @Totor: I am afraid that it's been a long long time since I looked at these.  I moved to using tmux and pretty much forgot all about screen.  In essence,  the commands are adding support for scroll to the term cap entry. You can probably find out more by reading the man page on termcap.

Comment: With KDE `konsole` I have to use `termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@` instead of `termcapinfo rxvt ti@:te@`. I am not familiar with this `termcap` stuff (neither with `tmux`) but shouldn't such configurations be more or less the same for `screen` and `tmux`?

Comment: @danielkullmann in your .screenrc

Comment: As well as replacing `rxvt` with `xterm` I had to comment out the last line to prevent output becoming corrupted.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Just noticed that you awarded me a bounty. Thank you!

Comment: For the record, this does work with the OS X terminal; I am going to make some edits to make it clear that `rxvt` may not work for everyone.

Comment: I agree with @Totor, I'd like to see an explanation of what each of these commands do, and why I may or may not want each of them, rather than copy-pasting magic that does who-knows-what.  There's a good explanation of `ti@:te@` over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen#answer-1125947 . The other thing (beginning with `hs:`) is still voodoo: I don't know what it does, nor its intent, nor why it's suggested for only rxvt and not rxvt-unicode too.  Since the `ti@:te@` entry alone seems to fix my problem, and I understand it, that's what I'm now using.

Answer (score 2):

check your $TERM variable to see what terminal you are actually using. If its xterm (or xterm*) use add this to ~/.screenrc to allow mouse scrolling:

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

or to be more complete:

```
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*|kterm*|Eterm* ti@:te@
```

absent modifying your ~/.screenrc, you can scroll with Ctrl-a ESC and then use up-down arrows. q to quit.

Note: you can also use your mouse to change focus between split windows via adding this to your ~/.screenrc

```
mousetrack on
```

Term Cap is a device independent terminal description library/database.

References/copies from:

[Terminal: termcapinfo command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153579/terminal-termcapinfo-command-not-found)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap

https://superuser.com/questions/629004/gnu-screen-change-focus-in-split-windows-with-mouse

Comment: This is the answer for macos... at least it is for `mojave` with default preferences for terminal.