# Terminal: termcapinfo command not found

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, xterm

I added the following line to my `.screenrc` script such that I can use my mouse to scroll up and down in the terminal when the output is too large and long. However, when I try to 
source `.screenrc` script. It complains that `termcapinfo command not found`.

`termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@`

I have no idea what went wrong ? Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not source it. The file `.screenrc` is read and interpreted by `screen` at start up.

Moreover please note that `termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@` will work only if your terminal set `$TERM` variable to `xterm`. In other case

```
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*|kterm*|Eterm* ti@:te@
```

is probably more universal solution.

There is also possibility to scroll by keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-a ESC` and then use up-down arrows.

Comment: okay. I added `termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@` . But I wasn't able to scroll up to see all the output . Why is this  ?

Comment: Which terminal do you use? Also `echo $TERM` will be usefull.

Comment: I am using Mac Terminal Version 2.4 (326). `echo $TERM` gives `xterm-256color`.

Comment: So use `termcapinfo xterm-256color ti@:te@` instead or even better `termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*|kterm*|Eterm*|screen* ti@:te@`

Comment: Yes. But how can I scroll up and down in only one screen ? Because I am currently in the 'screen' mode with the terminal printing the output of my python script on the left hand side and the python script(vim ) on right hand side. Is this even possible ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about your set-up, but please note that the "standard" way of of scrolling in `screen` is to use keyboard shortcut `C-a ESC` and then use up-down arrows. Try it, maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I knew that already. But I have a long list of output thats why i want to do scrolling. Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: @Thomas Ng Please ask separate question describing exactly what is your screen setup and where the problem lies. I think we deviated from the original question too much. I've edited my answer to summarize what we discussed so far.

Comment: @jimmij I have the same problem. I have three split screen windows and I need to use mouse scroll wheel to scroll up-down in each one separately. Using up-down arrows is not practical for me as I have long list of outputs while running my program and I need to use my mouse scroll wheel to scroll up-down. I have added termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*|kterm*|Eterm*|screen* ti@:te@  to my .screenrc, but still when I use scroll wheel it does not scroll inside the split screen.

Comment: In my case this solution did not work: using the scroll wheel nothing happened. This worked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40242/scroll-inside-screen-or-pause-output