# Make screen work like a terminal (scrolling + alternate screen)

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, scrolling

I would like to use `screen` (from GNOME Terminal, via `ssh`) like I use GNOME Terminal without `screen`, or as close as possible to that. Specifically:

In GNOME Terminal, I can scroll back using the mouse wheel, the scrollbar or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.
In `screen`, I have to go to copy mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd>) to be able to scroll back (mouse wheel works after that). **Scrolling behavior can be changed** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43229/is-there-a-way-to-make-screen-scroll-like-a-normal-terminal)) but this solution **has the following flaws**:

1. When I open a file with `less` or `vim`, I can scroll above the editor 'window' with my mouse wheel and see the previous contents of the terminal.
2. When I close the editor, its contents stay in the scrollback buffer (sometimes in several copies) instead of disappearing.

This behavior can be changed using `altscreen on` (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/23144/how-to-make-screen-terminal-emulation-act-more-like-xterm-or-rxvt-for-init-unini)) but the only effect is that when the editor is closed, the old terminal contents are *appended* to the scrollback buffer in my terminal window so I can still see the editor crap when I scroll back using my mouse wheel.

Does this mean it's not possible to have nice scrolling in `screen`? Basically, all I'd like is being able to scroll just like in copy mode (using the mouse wheel, and scrollbar if possible) but without having to enter copy mode.

Comment: [This question appears to have already been answered on this very site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43246).

Comment: @dsclose I linked this answer which seems to do the same thing: [Using the scrollwheel in GNU screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen)

Comment: Does it have to be screen? For example [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) has mouse scrolling support.

Comment: @Gert Thanks for the tip. I checked out `tmux` and it works fine. But it's not installed on the machine I'm `ssh`-ing into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you cannot have what you are asking.

From the terminal's standpoint:

- `screen` is a full-screen (no pun) application just like `vi` or `less`.
- the terminal implements scrolling and an alternate screen.
- when the terminal is in alternate-screen mode, it does not add to its scrollback area as it would in normal mode.
- in gnome-terminal (and perhaps some others — an option in xterm), the terminal will send up/down arrow keys to the *application* when it is in alternate-screen mode.
- when *not* in alternate screen mode, your terminal will scroll through the visible screen and the terminal's scrollback area without any notification to the application running inside it.

From `screen`:

- `screen` does not ***know*** anything about mice or scrolling; it passes that information to the application running inside `screen`.
- `screen` ***simulates*** an alternate screen; it has no way to access the alternate screen of the terminal.
- you can disable the alternate screen feature of the terminal, as indicated in the question.

In short, because `screen` does not have any way to access the scrollback of the terminal, your available choices are those that the terminal provides.

Comment: So `screen` runs in alternate screen mode by default but when I put `altscreen on` in `.screenrc`, `screen` tries to simulate one and turns it off in the terminal, right? And `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@` tells `screen` not to capture the mouse wheel so it's caught by the terminal and used for scrolling?

Comment: yes - except that screen's altscreen is simulated, whether or not the terminal supports the feature.

Comment: I'm trying to map mouse events using Termion (a Rust library) on an alternate screen. I'm using Terminator terminal, and it seems indeed it maps scrollwheel to up/down. Wondering if there's a way to avoid that and use my custom mappings.

Comment: But, in theory, it should be possible to have a keystroke in screen that
- switches to not altscreen
- dumps all content of currently active window to the terminal (to fill scrollback)
- from now on passes all output verbatim to the terminal while recording it internally in case of attaching later?

Of course, only with a single window, and there would have to be an option to turn it off again so you can use copy mode or split mode again.