# Scroll in Linux Screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, macos

I ssh into an ubuntu machine from a MAC. I have some screens running on the ubuntu machine. I attach to a screen using `screen -r <name of screen>` command. How do I look at the output of previous commands I have run on the screen? For example, when I use the scroll bar, I do not see the previous output.

Following are what I have tried so far -

1. `Cmd` + `A`, `:scrollback 1000`
2. `Cmd` + `A`, `ESC`, `Up Arrow`
3. Created `~/.screenrc` file and added

   ```
   shell "/usr/bin/bash"
   termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
   ```
4. `Cmd` + `A`, `Cmd` + `F` to search for previous outputs. This worked but it only searched in text that was on the screen. I need to search for previous text that is not visible on the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll inside Screen, or Pause Output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40242/scroll-inside-screen-or-pause-output)

Comment: It's not Cmd you should be using, but Ctrl

Comment: @roaima I am on a MAC connecting to a remote ubuntu server. That is why I am using `CMD`.

Comment: I've just rechecked. Standard Mac `Terminal` and then `ssh remoteSystem` and then attaching with `screen -r`. It's definitely _not_ Cmd that you should be using, but the standard `screen` keys. So [Ctrl A] [Esc] and then `↑` (up), `↓` (down), `/` (search), etc.